# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter in Intellij using grails 3.0.0

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I imported a Grails project in IntelliJ 14.1 and I got this exception when I tried to run the project using run-app command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\grails-3.0.0 -Dbase.dir=E:\Aurora\Cloned\funned\src300\papafund-web "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\grails-3.0.0/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -javaagent:C:\grails-3.0.0\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\grails-3.0.0\dist\grails-bootstrap-3.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\grails-3.0.0/conf/groovy-starter.conf "run-app -plain-output"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: idea support grails 3? i guess you will have an easier time when you treat it as a gradle project

Answer (score 7):

IntelliJ doesn't support Grails 3 yet - it has been requested [in their bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136970).

You can easily run the app from a commandline and use the IDE as an editor.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij Idea 15 supports Grails 3 or higher. You can see from the following: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-grails-3.html